# What conditions prevent PerformClick from working but allow InvokeOnClick to work?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to debug a winforms application where a working form in a process has been reused in a second process.  The form will present buttons to the user after a specified time of waiting.  In its original process, these buttons work fine.  In the secondary process, these buttons do not.

In investigating this, I progressed backwards, first making sure I could explicitly call the event handler(which worked), and then tried a call to PerformClick. The event handler did not get called with PerformClick.  Further looking around led me to InvokeOnClick, which does trigger the event handler so clearly there is some condition I need to fix in the second process that is blocking access to the buttons.

The only definition I found as to why InvokeOnClick works when PerformClick does not is that 'PerformClick checks that the button is 'available' before raising the click event'.  I checked at breakpoints that the button is both visible and enabled, what other conditions should I look for?

**UPDATE:** Well...back to baffled, three strikes on the things to check.  Confirmed there are no validation event handlers on the form, and CanSelect returns true.  From MSDN:

> This property returns true if the Selectable value of System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles is set to true, is contained in another control, the control itself is visible and enabled, and all its parent controls are visible and enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know:

- The button and *all of its parents* must be enabled and visible
- The control must be selectable (`ControlStyles.Selectable`)
- The validation rules must be fulfilled

Unless you're manually messing with `ControlStyles`, the likeliest are that either there's a failed validation in the button's validation group (*or* something that prevents a control-to-be-validated from changing focus), or that one of the parents of the button in question is disabled and/or invisible.

Comment: I was about to write basically the *exact* same answer, so +1 :-) For completeness sake, I'd also add that the delegate must be actually added to the button's `click` event by the time you call `PerformClick`, which sounds *too obvious* but might be worth checking if something hasn't actually removed it (or it's added at a later stage)

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  Pretty sure we have no validation rules in place for this particular form, so off I go into the chain of ownership and selectable status

Answer (score 4):

To add to @Luaan 's, answer, `InvokeOnClick` just calls the `OnClick` function of the control. It doesn't check for anything. This is the source of `InvokeOnClick` ([Link to Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,7787))

```
protected void InvokeOnClick(Control toInvoke, EventArgs e) {
  if (toInvoke != null) {
    toInvoke.OnClick(e);
  }
}
```

Where as this is the code for `PerformClick` ([Link to Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Button.cs,327))

```
public void PerformClick() {
  if (CanSelect) {
     bool validatedControlAllowsFocusChange;
     bool validate = ValidateActiveControl(out validatedControlAllowsFocusChange);
     if (!ValidationCancelled && (validate || validatedControlAllowsFocusChange))
     {
       //Paint in raised state...
       ResetFlagsandPaint();
       OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
     }
  }
}
```

`CanSelect` is implemented like:

```
if ((controlStyle & ControlStyles.Selectable) != ControlStyles.Selectable) {
  return false;
}
for (Control ctl = this; ctl != null; ctl = ctl.parent) {
  if (!ctl.Enabled || !ctl.Visible) {
     return false;
  }
}
```

So I'm basically adding to @Luaan 's answer, which is completely right: no need to explain further (his explanations are 100% right), and I'm just adding the proof :-)

Comment: Thanks for the proof, and the reference source links as well!  Winforms is still a bit strange and confusing to a mostly web app developer.