# what is the difference between Control.OnClick and Control.InvokeOnClick

Tags: c#, click, controls

i'm just wondering what the difference is between Control.OnClick and Control.InvokeOnClick methods.

the second thing i wonder ise, when it is asp.net they talk about 3 componenets: Click event, OnClick method, and button1_click eventhandler. but when it is desktop appcliatons they talk about only 2 componenets, Click event and its eventhandler. why is the onclik(invokeonclick) not mentioned at all?

Answer (score 1):

OnClick allows you to add a handler for when the Click event occurs on the control.
[InvokeOnClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokeonclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) will "Raise the Click event for the specified control".

So if you have assigned a *handler* to **OnClick** and then call **InvokeOnClick** on that control then your *handler* will be called.

Web is different. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156327/how-to-call-a-code-behinds-button-click-event-using-javascript) may help you for invoking click on a 'web' button.

Comment: there is also PerformClick. i'm totally confused.

Comment: this answer might help with Perform vs Invoke (scroll down to Jcl answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345551/what-conditions-prevent-performclick-from-working-but-allow-invokeonclick-to-wor